# Bootstrapping GAM LOESS models with Multiple Predictors

Tags: machine-learning, bootstrap, generalized-additive-model, loess

I have a data set with multiple predictors and am using a GAM model in conjunction with LOESS. I am trying to replicate this but include the bootstrap process as well. The following code is the prediction without using the bootstrap, using the gam package in R as mgcv does not implement LOESS models

```
Insight.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'Insight']
ignoreObsess.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'ignoreObsess']
rightQuick.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'rightQuick']
formalGut.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'formalGut']
protectCreate.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'protectCreate']
pointedHidden.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'pointedHidden']
Curiosity.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'Curiosity']
Experiment.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'Experiment']
Outcome.gam <- data.b.imputed.new[, 'Outcome']

out <- gam(Outcome.gam ~ lo(Insight.gam, span = 0.25) + lo(ignoreObsess.gam) + 
             lo(rightQuick.gam) + lo(formalGut.gam) +
             lo(protectCreate.gam) + lo(pointedHidden.gam) +
             lo(Curiosity.gam) + lo(Experiment.gam))

pred.star <- predict(out,
                     newdata = data.frame(data.b.imputed.new$Outcome))
mean((pred.star-Outcome.gam)^2)
```

I obtain a prediction error of approximately 2.118 however when using the bootstrap the prediction error is approximately 8.840 using the code below

```
n <- length(Outcome.gam)
nboot <- 2000
lmse.star <- double(nboot)

set.seed(17)
for (i in 1:nboot) {
  k.star <- sample(n, replace = TRUE)
  Insight.star <- Insight.gam[k.star]
  ignore.star <- ignoreObsess.gam[k.star]
  right.star <- rightQuick.gam[k.star]
  formal.star <- formalGut.gam[k.star]
  protect.star <- protectCreate.gam[k.star]
  point.star <- pointedHidden.gam[k.star]
  curiosity.star <- Curiosity.gam[k.star]
  exper.star <- Experiment.gam[k.star]

  Outcome.star <- Outcome.gam[k.star]
  
  # loess gam model
  out.star <- gam(Outcome.star ~ lo(Insight.star, span = 0.35) + lo(ignore.star) + 
                               lo(right.star) + lo(formal.star) +
                               lo(protect.star) + lo(point.star) +
                               lo(curiosity.star) + lo(exper.star))
  pred.star <- predict(out.star,
                       newdata = data.frame(data.b.imputed.new$Outcome))
  lmse.star[i] <- mean((Outcome.gam - pred.star)^2)
  
}
```

If I order the data according to the response, with the corresponding predictors the prediction error is approximately 0.04.
There is a significant difference in the MSPE of the bootstrap in comparison to the original value, is this code correct?